# Error parsing : mime-types\package.json: Unexpected token <

Tags: json, node.js

I'm working on a project on webStorm and when running it keeps giving me that error "package.json: Unexpected token <" and here is my json file :

```
{ "name": "GP_Panoramic_Tourism",
   "version": "0.0.0",
   "private": true,
   "scripts": {
   "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
 "dependencies": {
"body-parser": "~1.13.2",
"cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
"debug": "~2.2.0",
"ejs": "~2.3.3",
"express": "~4.13.1",
"kinect2": "^0.1.1",
"morgan": "~1.6.1",
"serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
    }
    }
```

and the error :

```
module.js:83
throw e;
^

 SyntaxError: Error parsing f:\Forth level First term material\GP       webSite\GP_Panoramic_Tourism\node_modules\mime-types\package.json: Unexpected    token <
at Object.parse (native)
at readPackage (module.js:79:52)
at tryPackage (module.js:89:13)
at Function.Module._findPath (module.js:152:20)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:335:25)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
at require (module.js:385:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (f:\Forth level First term material\GP webSite\GP_Panoramic_Tourism\node_modules\type-is\index.js:16:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
at require (module.js:385:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (f:\Forth level First term material\GP webSite\GP_Panoramic_Tourism\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\urlencoded.js:21:14)
```

Can you help me, please?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I see there is no syntax error on your JSON file. Would you tell me which line is errorneous?

Comment: @Nichar i edited the question with error appeared